# PhoneRTC 64 bit Support?

Tags: ios, cordova, 64-bit, phonertc

[PhoneRTC](http://phonertc.io/) doesn't currently support 64 bit devices. From 1st February 2015, [Apple requires all iOS apps to support 64 bit devices](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=10202014a).

Therefore, very soon PhoneRTC will no longer be a viable option for including video chat in an iOS application. This issue has been reported on [PhoneRTC's repository on Github](https://github.com/alongubkin/phonertc/issues/122), but so far nobody has taken it on.

Does anybody know of either a way that PhoneRTC can be made to support 64 bit devices, or a suitable alternative?

Comment: Only alternative I am aware of would be OpenTok, but it is not opensource. So it is quite different solution.

Comment: time for someone to write a valid phonegap/cordova webRTC plugin, i really wish someone will start a valid new one exposing more API from the native side  to the phonegap view

Comment: @MarkVeenstra thanks, I'll look into that as an alternative if this doesn't come off.

Comment: @sbaaaang yeah.. If I had the time and expertise I'd do it myself!

Comment: Someone from PhoneRTC just needs to get on this otherwise the whole wonderful project (The only free solution for Cordova) is lost.

Comment: Well at this moment you could go for a SIP with WebRTC solution. Using JSSIP + Crosswalk + Cordova. Crosswalk enables WebRTC in the Webview. Only IOS is not supported (yet). @sbaaaang

Comment: @MarkVeenstra WebRTC = free , any other alternative to webRTC costs in terms of money and servers or is not fully supported unfortunately

Comment: What i am wondering is why nobody is starting a new project to support webRTC on cordova, if only i was good at native i'd start it now!

Comment: @sbaaaang jssip + cordova + crosswalk is all opensource so no costs there

Comment: @MarkVeenstra ok but you talk about Android only

Answer (score 2):

I have made a fork of the github where i have added support for arm64.
Just remember to download the binary file for ios seperatly from google drive.
Link is in the description of the project.

https://github.com/MartySchmidt/phonertc

I have also changed the process after one adds it to a cordova project, but the console will write the new steps, when you add it.