# clang error : Apple Mach-O Linker Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I found many questions with this issue on StackOverflow but none of them addressed the issue I am having.

I am building [phonertc](http://phonertc.io) on XCode. It required me to perform the following steps on XCode which I did:

3) In General, change Deployment Target to 7.0 or above

4) Go to Build Settings and change:

a. Valid Architectures => armv7

b. Build Active Architecture Only => No

c. Runpath Search Paths => $(inherited) @executable_path/Frameworks

d. Objective-C Bridging Header => [ProjectName]/Plugins/com.dooble.phonertc/Bridging-Header.h

e. Embedded content contains Swift Code => yes

More can be found [here](https://github.com/alongubkin/phonertc/wiki/Installation)

On step 'd', there are many files in the given directory with Bridging header.h. I had given the path as told in the step but when I compile it gives the following error.

[image]

If we look carefully, we can see that '/'s are removed in the address. I don't understand how they are removed when I gave the correct address for bridging header.

It should take the correct address which is :

/../platforms/ios/HelloCordova/Plugins/com.dooble.phonertc/...

but it takes

/../platforms/ios/HelloCordovaPluginscom.dooble.phonertc...

I also tried to change the location to absolute location for bridging header. Look at the following image:

[image]

Comment: What you are showing is a **NOT** a compile error, but rather a linking error. For the second image, you are showing us a complier setting. I think you should also make sure that you have added the library's ***.a** files to the project, have you?

Comment: You are right, it is a linker error as I have mentioned, I did not call it compile error... do you know how to solve it?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea. But it may be a 32-bit vs 64-bit linking issue. Hope this one may help you a little bit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28087075/phonertc-64-bit-support. If you tried to link a 32-bit libaray for 64-bit app, you will probably get linking error like this as well.